# binding similar custom layers in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I've created 2 custom layers in Scapy which are very similar. They are both UDP and have the same length, but have different fields.

```
class Message_1(Packet):
    name = "Message_1"
    len = 10
    fields_desc = [
        BitField("TYPE", 1, size=4),
        BitField("A", 0, size=3),
        BitField("B", 0, size=1),
        BitField("C", 0, size=4),
        BitField("D", 0, size=4)
    ]

class Message_2(Packet):
    name = "Message_2"
    len = 10
    fields_desc = [
        BitField("TYPE", 2, size=4),
        BitField("V", 0, size=1),
        BitField("W", 0, size=2),
        BitField("X", 0, size=1),
        BitField("Y", 0, size=4),
        BitField("Z", 0, size=4)
    ]
```

I'm trying to bind the layers so I can parse the packets that are captured, but I can't figure out how to differentiate the layers. I think I should be using guess_payload_class but I don't understand how.

EDIT - I setup Scapy's sniffer and send 2 packets, 1 is Message_1 and the 2nd is Message_2. When I try to parse a captured packet Scapy thinks both packets are Message_1 because they're both UDP and length 10. I need to find a way to use the TYPE field to determine if the packet is a Message_1 or Message_2.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "differentiate the layers?"

Comment: @RossJacobs I edited my post to try and elaborate.

Comment: "I setup Scapy's sniffer and send 2 packets", "When I try to parse..." => Can you add relevant code? If you make this question an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then it's easier for me and others to replicate what you're talking about and help you.

Comment: I think you'd use bindlayers(UDP, Message_1, Type = 1) and bindlayers(UDP, Message_2, Type = 2). Not sure if I have the syntax 100%.